# Struggling with dynamics ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I am a MATLAB user.
What is the easiest way to port the following MATLAB script to python

```
a = []
for i=1:10
    for j=1:10
        a(i,j) =  i*j
    end
end
```

The question is about dynamically use np.ndarrays. In MATLAB I can initialize a as generical ndarray(via a=[]) without knowing its size, then use the explicit indexing a(i,j).
In Python there is the .append method, but when using ndarrays it confuses me, because it would require to pack element of a row first, then pack rows together, or something similar. I would prefer explicit indexing. Is this possible togheter with dynamical arrays or it can be done just with fixed size arrays?

Thanks!

Comment: For loops and dynamic allocation are a bad practice, in Matlab as in Python.

Comment: Start with `a=np.zeros((10,10), dtype=int)` if you must iterate like that.

Comment: MATLAB's arrays aren't actually dynamic.  Like numpy arrays, you cannot resize a MATLAB array without creating a new array and copying all the data over.  It is just that MATLAB pretends to resize them while numpy doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the display when you run the MATLAB

```
a =  1
a =
   1   2
a =
   1   2   3
a =
   1   2   3   4
.... (so on for 100 iterations)
```

In Octave I can do:

```
>> i=1:10
i =

    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10

>> j=(1:10)'
j =

    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
   10

>> a=i+j
a =

    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17
    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
```

This makes use of broadcasting, a concept borrowed from numpy

```
In [500]: i=np.arange(1,11)
In [501]: a = i[:,None] + i
In [502]: a
Out[502]: 
array([[ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])
```

This is best practice - in numpy and I dare say MATLAB and Octave.

But if you must use iteration do something like

```
In [503]: a=np.zeros((10,10),int)
In [504]: for i in range(10):
     ...:     for j in range(10):
     ...:         a[i,j]=i+j
```

Or with full blown python list iteration:

```
In [512]: alist = []
In [513]: for i in range(10):
     ...:     sublist=[]
     ...:     for j in range(10):
     ...:         sublist.append(i+j)
     ...:     alist.append(sublist)
     ...:     
In [514]: alist
Out[514]: 
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
 [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
 [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]
In [515]: np.array(alist)
Out[515]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]])
```

but I can generate `alist` more compactly with

```
alist=[[i+j for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
```

When you build a list of lists, make sure the sublists all have the same length - or else you'll come back to SO with question.