# Storing Dynamically in an array python

Tags: arrays, matlab, python-2.7, numpy

I am actually translating a matlab script into python an i have a problem using arrays in python (I am still a beginner) numpy.
My question is this:
In matlab I am computing the fourier transform of several signals and I am storing dynamically it in a 3 by 3 array say U. A simple example of what i want to do is as follows;

```
l = 3 ;
c = 0 ;
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:10
        c=c+1 ;
        a = j + 1;
        U(i,c,:)=a ;
    end 
end
```

I want to translate this to python and I am unable to create the array U that stores dynamically the value of 'a' in U. 
Note : Here am computing 'a' as j+1 for simplicity but in my script 'a' is an array (the fourier transform of a signal)

Sorry for my bad english, I am french. T

Comment: What is the python code that you've tried? What errors are you getting? Assignment works very similarly in `numpy`.

Comment: MATLAB grows an matrix as you assign to it.  `numpy` requires that you initialize an array of the correct size first.  See this recent question, also titled `dynamically`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041016/struggling-with-dynamics-ndarray

Comment: It seems like you know the size of the array beforehand. So you can first pre-allocate the array as: `mat = np.empty(shape=(3, 30))`. Check if I got the shape right.

Comment: @hpaulj Technically MATLAB doesn't grow the array, it creates a new array and copies all the data over.  It is extremely slow and you shouldn't be doing it in this situation.  You can do the same thing in numpy if you really wanted to.  The difference is that numpy makes you do the copy explicitly so people aren't fooled into thinking the array is somehow dynamically size.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will ultimately want something like this. One of the things that was confusing was what your loop variable c and j were doing. It seems like you wanted c=j, so I changed that below. The one thing you need to watch out for is that python objects are indexed from 0, whereas Matlab objects are index from 1. So below, if you actually start examining the values of i and j, you will see that they start from 0.

```
import numpy
L = 3;
C = 10;
N = 50; # Size of the Fourier array
U = numpy.zeros((L,C,N))
for i in range(L):
    for j in range(C):
        # Create a matrix of scalars, for testing
        a           = i*j*numpy.ones((N,));
        U[i,j,:]    = a;
```

Comment: Thank's very much! it's exactly what I wanted

Comment: I have question on the dimensions of U, normally it's has dimension 3 but when I do np.shape(U[1,2,:]) U seems to have a dimension of 2

Comment: Right because you are pulling off a submarine in that case. Please mark the answer correct if it is.

Comment: I still don't understand why the dimension is not 3

Comment: Because you are extract a matrix the the same size as 'a', and 'a' has only 2 dimesions.  You can think of the 3rd dimension being implicitly equal to 1.

Comment: Ok I see. I will try to seek into it further, but why the difference with matlab?

Comment: Matlab doesn't do the implicit conversion. In Matlab,  you are actually getting a 2d array back because one of the dimensions will be 1.

Comment: For instance, you can see what happens when you call 'squeeze' in Matlab on the returned array

Comment: I have a problem with your answer, it don't really understand it assigns values. when I try to span my array manually I see that i have zeros for some values of j.

Comment: Yes because python indexes start at 0. So if you actually loo at what values j takes, it goes from 0 to c-1

Comment: yeah but normally j and i are indices that will help me reference my array 'a' for a given position ij. So if i call say for example U[0,1,:] i should have no zeros so far as my array 'a' contains no zero.

Comment: @lefloxy: in numpy, taking a single index reduces the dimensions while taking a slice doesn't.  So if `a` is a 3D array, `a[0, :, :]` will be a 2D array, while `a[:1, :, :]` will be a 3D array with identical elements.  MATLAB doesn't have an easy way to do this sort of dimension reduction, nor would it really be possible for it to because MATLAB matrices must have at least two dimensions (there are no 1D or 0D matrices in MATLAB), so if MATLAB worked like numpy then `a(1, :, :)` would be 2D, but `a(1, 1, :)` would also be 2D, and even `a(1, 1, 1)` would be 2D.

Comment: @lefloxy: remember that the first values of `i` and `j` in the loop are zero.  So say `i` is `5` and `j` is `0`, then `i*j*numpy.ones((N,))` is `5*0*numpy.ones((N,))`, which is an array of all zeros.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Thank's very much, it is much clearer now