# Python equivalent to MATLAB's dynamic array initialization

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, python-2.7, numpy

In MATLAB, I can create an array and assign values to it dynamically without mentioning the size of the array while its creation.  I'm new to MATLAB, the following show how I create an array and assign values to it in MATLAB.

```
>> a=[]
a = 
     []

>> a(2,2) = 55
a = 
     0   0
     0   55
```

We can write a function in Python to do this but I want to know that is there any equivalent procedure to MATLAB functionality of assigning values to array dynamically in Python or in Numpy?

Comment: That's a bad way of assigning values in MATLAB. Changing the size of an array is not a good idea

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041016/struggling-with-dynamics-ndarray; MATLAB grows the matrix by creating a new one with each assignment.  It's not the same as `Python` list `append`.